# Is there any advantage to using candles instead of the flashlight?

Tags: phasmophobia

In phasmophobia, hunters can buy and use candles.

I wonder what is the use of candles? How are they better than the good old flashlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages that candles appear to have over flashlights are:

- They are not affected during a Hunt, whereas flashlights will flicker and turn off.
- They can be deployed, illuminating areas they are deployed in.
- Light produced by a candle emanates in all directions from the flame, unlike the directional bulb of a flashlight
- Players can use them as navigation markers, denoting areas you've been or for finding your way around a map.
- Ghosts can blow out candles, which may sound like a con, but also can be helpful in denoting that a ghost is nearby.
- Candles can be used to light smudge sticks or other candles allowing players to have both a source of fire and illumination

One additional note that the [Wiki](https://phasmophobia.fandom.com/wiki/Candle) states for candles is that purchased candles appear to be brighter than those found on maps.  So if candles are often used as part of your strategy, purchased candles may be more advantageous.

Comment: Additionally, I don't believe ghosts detect lit candles while hunting, but they will detect  electronics that are on.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention, but with updates Lit Candles reduce Sanity Drain.